# function runs only when invoked?

Tags: python-2.7

This is probably a dumb question but i need to be sure only about one thing in this case. So i have this:

```
from __future__ import print_function   
a_var = 10
b_var = 15
c_var = 25

def f_a_func(a_var):
   print ('in f_a_func a_var = ',a_var)
   b_var = 100 + a_var
   d_var = 2 * a_var
   print ('in f_a_func b_var = ',b_var)
   print ('in f_a_func d_var = ',d_var)
   print ('in f_a_func c_var = ',c_var)
   return (b_var + 10)

#c_var = f_a_func(b_var)

print ('a_var =',a_var)
print ('b_var =',b_var)
print ('c_var =',c_var)
print ('d_var =',d_var)
```

When i run this whole file the function only compiles, but doesn't executes right? And when i remove the '#' before c_var then it is invoked compiled and executed. I will remove this embarrassed question as soon as i clarify this. Thanks.

Comment: *"When i run this whole file the function only compiles, but doesn't executes right?"* - no, it will be executed (for example, the `print` lines will run), only the commented-out line won't be executed. Why don't you **try it and see**?!

Comment: it doesn't executes, but i just needed to be sure that this is happening

Comment: The function call won't execute, as it's commented out, but other things ought to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to execute a function you have to call it.

Commented code is neither compiled nor executed.